# RouteCollection.php line 161

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-rotas

Fiz o desenvolvimento de uma aplicação `PHP` utilizando **Laravel** em um computador, quando copiei este mesmo projeto para outro computador e executo o mesmo, ocorre o erro de rota abaixo:

```
NotFoundHttpException in
   C:\wamp64\www\BuscaPet\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php 
     line 161: in RouteCollection.php line 161 
  at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 780 
  at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 610 
  at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 596 
  at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 267 
  at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53 
  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in  CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46 
  at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137 
  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33 
  at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in  Pipeline.php line 104 
  at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149 
  at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116 
  at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

No computador que realizei o desenvolvimento, ao executar, quando acesso as outras páginas, tudo ocorre normalmente sem erros, porém o mesmo projeto em outro computador aponta o erro de rotas quando acesso outras páginas.

Comment: Stackoverflow em Português, faça as devidas tradução para português!

Comment: Traduzido Virgilio, obrigado.

Comment: Só com essas informações não vou conseguir ajudar, tente, colocar um passo a passo do que foi esse transporte de uma maquina para outra?

Comment: *Computador 1*
1º Instalação do WampServer
2º Instalação do framework Larave 5.3, utilizando o composer
3º Executado o comando 'laravel new MinhaAplicacao' pelo cmd, dentro da pasta c:/Wamp64/www
4º Todo desenvolvimento do site neste projeto criado.

*Computador 2*
1º Copiei a aplicação dentro da pasta c:/Wamp64/www/aplicacao
2º Ao executar a aplicação e acessar outra página, apresenta o erro novamente.

Comment: a pasta do wamp começa é `c:/Wamp64/www/` e você criou um subpasta e colocou o projeto do Laravel?

Comment: Exatamente, o comando 'laravel new MinhaAplicacao' executado no cmd c:\wamp64\www> cria o diretório MinhaAplicacao

Copiei a pasta MinhaAplicacao deste diretório e no outro computador colei dentro de c:/wamp64/www/(PastaColada)

Comment: O laravel possui uma configuração que o site tem que ser iniciado na pasta `public/` para que tudo funcione perfeito, você tem que configurar o seu wamp configurando esse diretório virtual para que ele funcione, caso contrário dá esses problemas!

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio, funcionou.

Comment: Seria interessante se o Virgilio colocasse o comentário como resposta e o Jonatas aceitasse, para ficar para registro no site...

Comment: O laravel possui uma configuração que o site tem que ser iniciado na pasta public/ para que tudo funcione perfeito, você tem que configurar o seu wamp configurando esse diretório virtual para que ele funcione, caso contrário dá esses problemas! Créditos para o Virgilio Novic